# Apple Watch app for hiking

Tags: applications, software-recommendation, apple-watch, gps

What's your favorite Apple Watch app for Hiking.
I'm looking for something that provide this features:

- Integration with Health and Activities (i.e. calories, heartbeat, distance, GPS map, workout etc)
- Shows relevant information while hiking (i.e. at least time, distance, and elevation)
- Works without iPhone
- Does not drain the Apple Watch battery too fast (the built-in workout app is fine in this terms, but too limited in functionalities)
- Ideally has a web interface to analyze the data (like Strava or Garmin Connect)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there are no apps that satisfy your needs.

The Apple Watch Series 2 can track your location using its GPS receiver, but it **can't determine your altitude/elevation** on its own. It's technically impossible. The GPS receiver in the Apple Watch Series 2 is not as capable as the one used in current iPhones.

---

You can, however, use an app like [ViewRanger](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/viewranger-outdoors-gps-open/id404581674) in conjunction with an iPhone 6, 6 Plus, 6s, 6s Plus, 7 or 7 Plus. These devices have built-in barometers that can be used to determine your altitude.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: That's not quite true: Signal from three GPS satellites gives you position and from four heights. May not be as accurate as with barometer but works. My 20 year old Garmin 12XL did that already fairly well. So the watch CAN - it just needs to WANT